# SCons: Get abspath of original file (as though I hadn't set variant_dir)

Tags: scons

I can use `File('foo.bar').abspath` to get the location of a file, but if I've got variant_dir set then the returned path will be in variant_dir rather than it's original location. If I have `duplicate=0` set, then the file returned won't actually exist.

Obviously SCons knows where the original file is, as it's passed as an argument when the file's actually built (eg `gcc -c -o variant/foo.o orig/foo.c`).

Is there some sort of `File('foo.bar').origpath` that I can use?

If it came to it I could use `os.path.join(Dir('#').abspath, 'orig')` but that requires the SConscript to know which directory it's in, which is messy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`srcnode()`](http://www.scons.org/doc/latest/HTML/scons-api/SCons.Node.FS.Base-class.html#srcnode). To quote the [man page](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.0.1/HTML/scons-man.html):

> The srcnode() method returns another
>   File or Dir object representing the
>   source path of the given File or Dir.

This will give you the absolute path in the source directory:

```
File('foo.bar').srcnode().abspath
```

Comment: Ah, beautiful! I knew there must be something like that. Thanks!