# Does scons know in which directory a SConscript file resides?

Tags: scons

We are evaluating scons as a build system, and I am having a problem accomodating our old system. In some of our source code subdirectories, we have a "sources.lib" file that lists the names of the C++ files that need to be compiled to assemble that directory's target library. But, there are additional C++ files in the same directory, so I can't just use Glob() to find the appropriate ones.

How do I find out which directory a SConscript file resides in? os.getcwd() always returns the build directory. Even though the documentation states that paths in a SConscript are relative to the source directory (or else Glob('*.cpp') wouldn't work), just doing an open('sources.lib') fails because it looks for the file in the build directory. Finally, the build environment in that SConscript file doesn't contain the actual current source directory.

**Edit** From [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066545/scons-get-abspath-of-original-file-as-though-i-hadnt-set-variant-dir) it looks like

```
File('sources.lib').srcnode().abspath
```

returns the proper filename and directory, **but** it won't tell you if it exists (must use os.path.isfile for that). It also appears that

```
Dir('.').srcnode().abspath
```

will tell you where the SConstruct file resides.

**Example** When defining which source files to compile for a library, I don't want to use

```
lib = env.SharedLibrary('mylib', Glob('*.cpp'))
```

but instead would rather construct a function that first checks for the existence of "sources.lib" and if it does not exist, use globbing. So I'm defining my library like so

```
lib = env.SharedLibrary('mylib', env.getSources('*.cpp'))
```

and making a function that reads the file if it exists

```
def getSources(self, pattern):

    # list of source files to assign to a target
    sources = []
    # srcFile = 'sources.lib' # failed
    # srcFile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sources.lib') # failed
    srcFile = File('sources.lib').srcnode().abspath # works

    # look for sources.lib
    try:
        infile = open(srcFile,'r')
    except IOError:
        #print "Globbing to get sources"
        sources = Glob(pattern, strings=True)
    else:
        #print "Reading sources.lib"
        for line in infile.readlines():
            line = line.rstrip('\n\r')
            if line != '':
                sources.append(line)

    return sources

buildEnv.AddMethod(getSources)
```

This seems to work. I didn't know about File.srcnode().abspath until today.

Comment: To determine if a file exists, you can use os.path.exists()

Comment: I don't understand your problem, create small example which illustrate it.

Comment: Your question saved me :) `Dir('.').srcnode().abspath` worked for me. I use this option `env.SConscriptChdir(0)` to avoid directory "slides". Thanks!

Comment: Me too! I was looking to form an additional python import path (for sys.path.append), based on the current SConscript location, and os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) did not work (no __file__ defined), but your Dir('.') method worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following code:

```
this_sconscript_file = (lambda x:x).func_code.co_filename
code_base = os.path.dirname(this_sconscript_file)
```

Comment: Doesn't `os.path.dirname(__file__)` do the same thing?

Comment: No, because scons includes SConscripts somehow in such a way, that `__file__` always refers the root script, even in included scripts.

Comment: Good workaround. I still think that `Dir('.').srcnode().abspath` is a nicer solution.

Comment: As a small follow-up, with Python 3 you need to replace `func_code` with `__code__`, so that the full command becomes `(lambda x:x).__code__.co_filename`.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 types of paths in SCons:

1. Relative to the root SConstruct prepending '#' to the path
2. Relative to the SConscript not using the '#'.
3. Absolute path. I think this is self-explanatory :)

If you need to deal with paths outside of the directory where the SConscript is, you should use the '#'

It should work both ways in this example, but the path with the '#' seems more explicit and  intuitive to me:

```
./SConstruct
./dirA/SConscript - use '#dirA/sources.lib' OR 'sources.lib'
./dirB/SConscript - use '#dirB/sources.lib' OR 'sources.lib'
```

Hope this helps,

Brady

Comment: According to the documentation the default relative path is to the curretn SConstruct file and not to where scons was executed.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just tested it too. Sorry for the confusion, I'll correct my answer. I had a problem with this once and was convinced that it was relative to from where scons was executed, for example if you're in a subdir and use 'scons -u', but that appears not to be the case. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: But what about the *current* SConscript, as opposed to the SConscript that actually calls a builder? In my case I'm trying to setup the common environment to be used by many sub-modules - this includes adding a `include/` dir in the current SConscript directory to CPPPATH.

Comment: Not sure I understand what your asking. A path in a particular SConscript, should be relative to that SConscript file, and shouldnt matter from where you call scons.